# Possible to get a report of email addresses that bounced from Amazon SES?

Tags: amazon-ses, email-bounces

While the SES dashboard shows aggregated statistics about the bounce rate of emails sent through the service, I do not see a way of retrieving the individual addresses that bounced.  Is this possible?  Our situation is that the 'from' address we had set in certain emails was incorrect and resolved to a non existant mailbox on our (verfied sender) domain, so anything SES would have forwarded to the from address is likely gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no, they are gone.  Lesson: make sure you from address is valid (good practice obviously) and goes to a mailbox that resolves (and/or set up and process a SQS queue for them to go to)

Answer (score 4):

Use the Amazon SNS (simple notification service), and then you can add your email address - or Amazon SQS service for holding a log of all bounces/complaints.

Comment: The question states the emails were already sent.  SNS/SQS or setting the email will only work for future emails.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Amazon SES account-level suppression list](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/sending-email-suppression-list.html) to view email addresses that was automatically added to this list due to hard bounces or complaints.

#### Enable Amazon SES account-level suppression list

If you are using Amazon SES after November 25 2019, this feature is automatically enabled. If you're using Amazon SES before this date, then you can enable it using `PutAccountSuppressionAttributes` API.

#### View Amazon SES account level suppression list

To view the list, use the following AWS CLI command:

```
aws sesv2 list-suppressed-destinations
```

To view the list using AWS Console, do the following:

1. Sign in to the AWS Management Console and open the Amazon SES
   console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/ses/.
2. In the navigation pane, under Configuration, choose Suppression
   list.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. The SES report didn't show enough details for the accruing bounce error. I modified the sesreport.zip, where the deliveries, from-emails/source-emails, and the subject column are added and are included in the report.

You can find my modification here: 
https://github.com/Morning-Train/AWS-SES-Report

I hope my answer helps you with your problem.